# Print a web page to a specific printer in client from chrome

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-chrome

I'm aware that I cannot do this with Html/JS. Can I do this with communicating to a installed program in OS from web page. There has to be a way.

It would be better if there is already some sort of solution

Comment: CTRL+P (or OS equivalent), select printer, click print.... why try to build something that is already part of most browsers

Comment: afaik, you can only set the default printer to the one you want JS to use...